# Python ipywidgets checkbox events

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I am using ipywidgets.widgets.Checkbox. Is there any way to handle the checkbox events? Please do help. I am a beginner.

edit: How to create a list of checkboxes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There aren't any direct events but you can use the `observe` [event](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html#Traitlet-events). That will likely create more events than you want so you may want to filter them down to one.

```
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import Checkbox

box = Checkbox(False, description='checker')
display(box)

def changed(b):
    print(b)

box.observe(changed)
```

To create a "list" of widgets you can use container [widgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html?highlight=vbox#Natural-sizes,-and-arrangements-using-HBox-and-VBox). From the link:

```
from ipywidgets import Button, HBox, VBox

words = ['correct', 'horse', 'battery', 'staple']
items = [Button(description=w) for w in words]
left_box = VBox([items[0], items[1]])
right_box = VBox([items[2], items[3]])
HBox([left_box, right_box])
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on Jacques' answer: If using [Jupyter Lab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab), rather than a standard Jupyter Notebook, you must also create an output widget and tell the callback function to write to it using a decorator. So the given example becomes:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

box = widgets.Checkbox(False, description='checker')
out = widgets.Output()

@out.capture()
def changed(b):
    print(b)

box.observe(changed)

display(box)
display(out)
```

These steps are documented [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Output%20Widget.html#), but it is obvious that they are required when using Jupyter Lab.